# How to fix image upload failures?

Tags: apache, php-7.2, dokuwiki

2 days ago I installed Dokuwiki on my shared server (OVH), on a subdomain.
Server requirements are ok for the install, and I followed [the official steps](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install).

Since the beginning, **I can't upload images**, when I try I get this error on my console : 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
[image: Here a screenshot]

What I tried :

1. I checked folder permissions, and even passed them to 777 in order to test.
2. I added `file_uploads=on` to `.ovhconfig` (similar to php.ini), it's activated but still doesn't work
3. I tried many file extensions, none uploads.
4. I checked `mime_config` file, no problem there

I didn't find anything else to try, but if you have any idea or question, **I will be glad to try/answer** 
Thank you very much !

*Note : I can't share the url for security reasons*

Comment: Thanks for the edit !
Does anyone have _any clue_ ?